# ¿Cómo puedo listar un valor establecido en mi select? ng-model

Tags: angularjs

Estoy modificando una compra y necesito que me cargue el proveedor que tiene esa compra en mi select, actualmente no lo carga se queda en blanco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que me liste el proveedor al que yo le realizé la compra.

```
<select name="mySelect" id="proveedor"class="form-control" ng-model="MCompra.PROVEEDOR">
    <option ng-repeat="datalist in listaproveedor" value="{{datalist.ID_PROVEEDOR}}">{{ datalist.NOMBRE | uppercase}}</option>
</select>
```

En el controller tengo esta función

```
        $scope.Modificar = function () {
            var compra = $scope.listacompra.filter(function (item) {
                return item.Seleccionado === true;
            });
            if (compra.length == 1) {
                CompraService.ListarCompra(compra, function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        $scope.MCompra = response.datos;
                        console.log($scope.MCompra);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

Al ejecutar esta función me trae todos los atributos que necesito, el unico problema es que no me lista el proveedor en mi select.

Answer (score 0):

En el controller que muestras, no aparece la variable listaproveedor por ningún lado. ¿Estas seguro que el nombre es correcto?

Te dejo un playground con tu código modificado para que puedas ver como funciona.

https://codepen.io/naimad/pen/xdyzZK

Un Saludo

Comment: Hola, el problema realmente es que a la hora de listar los valores en mis input lo hace bien, pero en los select no.

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a cambiar el value por ng-value? Muy probablemente se deba a que te está tomando el valor que le pones al value como un String.  Te dejo el ejemplo editado: https://codepen.io/naimad/pen/xdyzZK

Comment: He realizado el cambio que me indicaste pero no cumplió con lo que esperaba.. lo que ocurre es que yo inicialmente selecciono modificar una compra, se me abre el modal y posterior a ello desearia que en el select me salga el proveedor al que le realice la compra. En el Select no sale el proveedor seleccionado (Este es mi error) sinó que sale en blanco, pero yo despliego el select y me aparecen correctamente todos los proveedores (Esto está correcto).

Answer (score 0):

he consultado un poco y obtuve una respuesta, esta me ayudó a solucionar el problema que tenia.

en la función que tengo en mi controller hize lo siguiente.. una vez me diera un resultado la funcion interna que era listarcompra llamaria otra nuevamente cambiando el valor del option de mi select que estaba en la vista.

```
   $scope.Modificar = function () {
        var compra = $scope.listacompra.filter(function (item) {
            return item.Seleccionado === true;
        });
        if (compra.length == 1) {
            CompraService.ListarCompra(compra, function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $scope.MCompra = response.datos;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $("#Proveedor > option[value='" + $scope.MCompra.PROVEEDOR + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
                            $("#tipopago > option[value='" + $scope.MCompra.TIPO_PAGO + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
                        });
                    console.log($scope.MCompra);
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

de esta manera al dar clic en el botón módificar se me cargarian en mis selects los datos que tenia al registrar esa compra.

AGRADEZCO LA AYUDA QUE ME BRINDARON!

SALU2